# In Django, how do I make a model that queries my legacy SQL Server and Oracle databases and sends that to the view?

Tags: django, django-models, data-migration

I have a lot of old vbscript webpages using Classis ASP.  Those ASP pages have lots of different databases queries to different databases all inside a given .asp file.  I want to write those in Python and use Django as the framework.  Will I be able to do this?  I'm not sure how to start after I install Django.  Sure, I can make a demo work, but that's not what I'm after.  I will use the normal database "things" in MySQL or PostgreSQL, but sooner or later I have to hit those other databases and bring them back into Django, using Django's templating and so on.

Will I be able to do this?  How do I make a model that queries my legacy SQL Server and Oracle database and send that to the view?  Am I "fighting the framework" to accomplish this?

Just to be clear.  I am not interested in messing with the stock database that Django uses for it's settings.  That can stay as it is.  I want to use that part for plugins, security (ldap), etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can query different databases in your ORM calls by leveraging the `using` statement: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#using

This would allow you to set up as many [database definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) as you need in settings.py, then specify which DB to query at the view level. That way, you wouldn't have to change your model definition should you decide to consolidate your databases, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed the Django [multiple databases documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)?

Django has a built-in Oracle back end, so that should be fairly straightforward.

SQL Server can work through [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/avidal/django-pyodbc) but I found it fairly painful to set up.  If you already have a generally working ODBC connection to your legacy SQL Server database connection from your Django environment it's no big deal, but it took me some trouble to get things set up to where I could use tsql to connect to my SQL Server database.

I also had some trouble with Unicode data from the SQL Server database until I forced it to use the appropriate (later) version of TDS.  I just needed it for a script or two, so I set the 'TDSVER' environment variable and left it at that, but in theory there are other places you can set that.